# Hibernate - Getting "MultipleBagFetchException" when using OneToOne, but not when using OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have 4 entities that I want to save in my database:

```
@Entity 
‰PNG


IHDR         àÌïH   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa    pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d   IDATWc¼ìÿŸ`‚Ò€ö q=†Kíò¢    IEND®B`‚
}
```

However, the above code does not work. I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [EventLocation.sections, Section.seats]
```

What I find weird about it is that if I change the "OneToOne" relationship between "Zoo" and "Animals" to a "OneToMany" relationship (so that Zoo contains a List of Animals instead of just one), then the above code works perfectly fine.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong about the code?